# How do I return multiple AppShortcuts for my AppShortcutsProvider

Tags: swift, siri

To make your iOS app automatically have Siri support (vs requiring users to add shortcuts manually), iOS16 offers App Shortcuts.

**I want to specify multiple Siri App Shortcuts -- one per intent**. But I got a bit stuck on this Swift syntax, I'm sure there's something simple going on.

A standard Swift snippet for adding app shortcuts is as below.

What confuses me is that `appShortcuts` is defined as a list of AppShortcuts (`[AppShortcut]`) but the initialiser is a single value (`AppShortcut`).

1. I don't understand how this compiles. Is there an extension or something that messes with the return type?
2. If I change it to return a list I get `Cannot convert value of type '[AppShortcut]' to expected argument type 'AppShortcut'` -- but I'm not enough of a Swift wiz to figure out why the expected argument type is indeed `AppShortcut`.

```
== AppIntents ==
...
public protocol AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] { get }
}
...

== My intent ==

import AppIntents
struct AppShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {
  @AppShortcutsBuilder
  static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
    AppShortcut(
      intent: OrderStatusIntent(),
      phrases: ["Where is my \(.applicationName) order?",
        "\(.applicationName) order status"]
    )
  }
}
```

If I create a snippet in Swift Playground all works as expected. A single item in a list.

```
public struct AppShortcut {
    var title: String
}

public protocol AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] { get }
}


struct BookShortcuts:AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut]{[
    AppShortcut(
        title:"one"
    )]
    }
}

print(BookShortcuts.appShortcuts)
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me:

```
import AppIntents
struct AppShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {
  @AppShortcutsBuilder
  static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
    AppShortcut(
      intent: OrderStatusIntent(),
      phrases: ["Where is my \(.applicationName) order?",
        "\(.applicationName) order status"],
      shortTitle: "Order Status"
    )
    AppShortcut(
      intent: OrderPriceIntent(),
      phrases: ["How much is my \(.applicationName) order?",
        "\(.applicationName) order price"],
      shortTitle: "Order Price"
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And the solution: the @AppShortcutsBuilder directive is a result builder which is a cosmetic compile-time directive to remove list brackets and commas (AFAICT I see no other use for it). If someone can school me on the functional value of it, that'd be really amazing.

Learn more about [result builders](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/deep-dive-into-swift-function-builders/)

Comment: Yep, result builders is the answer. You just list the app shortcuts like a list of independent statements. This is a language feature created to support SwiftUI but can be also used for other use cases like this

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `,` between the AppShortcuts:

```
@AppShortcutsBuilder static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
    AppShortcut(...) // avoid ,
    AppShortcut(...) // avoid ,
    AppShortcut(...)
}
```